# Sort array using probability distributon

Tags: php, arrays, math, probability

An array shall be sorted high to low by its values.

```
<?php
$items = array(
  1 => f(1),
  2 => f(2),
  3 => f(3),
  4 => f(4),
  5 => f(5),
);
?>
```

After sorting I look which item 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 is the first one. I try that again and again and again.
Afterwards

- 5 should be the first item five times more than 1
- 4 should be the first item four times more than 1
- 3 should be the first item three times more than 1
- 4 should be the first item two times more than 2
- ...

One idea is

```
<?php
function f(key) {
  return key / random();
}
?>
```

which, for 1'000'000 tries resulted in

```
key | times on top | ratio with key one | expected ratio
----+--------------+--------------------+---------------
 5  |      374'365 | 6.75               | 5
 4  |      267'863 | 4.83               | 4
 3  |      185'707 | i am so lazy ...   | 3
 2  |      116'618 |                    | 2
 1  |       55'447 | 1                  | 1
```

Looks wierd to me, but maybe

- there is a simple problem with f?
- there is a better f?

---

My implementation:

```
<?php

abstract class Test {

  private $result;

  protected abstract function f($x);

  protected function iteration() {
    $values = array(
      1 => $this->f(1),
      2 => $this->f(2),
      3 => $this->f(3),
      4 => $this->f(4),
      5 => $this->f(5),
    );

    arsort($values);

    $top = key($values);

    if (!isset($this->result[$top])) {
      $this->result[$top] = 1;
    } else {
      $this->result[$top]++;
    }
  }

  public function run($iterations) {
    $this->result = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < $iterations; $i++) {
      $this->iteration();
    }
    arsort($this->result);
    return $this->result;
  }
}

class MyTest extends Test {
  protected function f($x) {
    return $x / rand();
  }
}

$test = new MyTest();
$result = $test->run(1000 * 1000);
print_r($result);
printf("Ratio of key 5 to 1, which should be 5: %f\n", $result[5] / $result[1]);

?>
```

---

I have tried a billion rounds. But again the ratio is 6.75 - **the whole point is: why isn't it five?**

---

The results for

```
<?php
class BetterRandomGeneratorTest extends Test {
  protected function f($x) {
    return $x / mt_rand();
  }
}
?>
```

are

```
Array
(
  [5] => 3742816
  [4] => 2674352
  [3] => 1861444
  [2] => 1168333
  [1] => 553055
)
Ratio of key 5 to 1: 6.767529
```

Comment: Strong Law of Large Numbers says it's true. Do a billion tries.

Comment: What are you looking for?! I don't understand if you are trying to understand why / how, or if you need help implementing whatever you are trying to do... Try being a little clearer on your question.

Comment: I agree. What is the `f(x)` supposed to accomplish?

Comment: Try other random number generators like mt_rand and see if you get better results.

Comment: @Frits van Campen: Added the results for mt_random to the question

Comment: If you throw performance out the window and just focus on accuracy, why not try something like: `$sum = 0; while($i < $key) { $i += 1; $sum += rand(0, 1); } return $sum;`

Comment: @Frits van Campen: Then f(1) is always 0. Using `$i` **<=** `key` I get a ratio of 67.53 (instead of 5) for 1 million tries. This does not look like an easy problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple f which will do it.

```
function f(key) {
  $x = 0;
  for($i = 0; $i < $key; $i++) {
    $y = random();
    if ($x < $y) {
      $x = $y;
    }
  }
  return $x;
}
```

This is guaranteed to work because the max is equally likely to be any of the 15 random numbers chosen, and 1/3 of the time that number will be in `f(5)`, versus 1/15 for `f(1)`.

As for what was wrong with your `f`, it is quite simple.  Your solution has the nice symmetry that exactly 80% of the time, `f(1) < f(5)`.  However `f(1)` tends to be bigger than `f(5)` when `f(1)` is larger than average *and* `f(5)` is smaller than average.  Ditto for `f(2)`, `f(3)` and `f(4)`.  However it is unusual for all of `f(2), ... f(5)` to be small at once.  This causes correlations that cause `f(1)` to be the largest less often than you would naively think.  Vice versa correlations tend to come out in favor of `f(5)` more often than you would naively think.

If you want to compute the exact probabilities of each number coming out on top, it shouldn't be too hard to compute exact answers with integration.  The idea is that you integrate from 0 to 1 the probability that, if that was the value of `random()` for `f(i)` that `f(i)` is the maximum.  (So, for instance, for 5 you would integrate `(1-x/5)(1-x/4)(1-x/3)(1-x/2)` while for 1 you would integrate a function that is 0 if `random()` is bigger than 0.2, and otherwise is `(1-2x)(1-3x)(1-4x)(1-5x)`.)  The expressions will be complicated, and the ratios won't come out to nice answers.

Comment: What is $iterations and where does $key go into it? -- The explanation is very nice.

Comment: @Niklas: That was a wrong variable name.  It should have been $key.  Fixed.